# Containers are not accessible to each other

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have had the problem since the beginning that I can not connect between two containers.

I have read and adjusted all available tutorials, but as it is presented in all these tutorials, it does not work for me.

I get from my app always the message that the connection was thrown back, no matter what kind of server I use. I tried it first with Redis as a cache service, then me the Mongo DB but always I get the message that the connection could not be made.

I'm new to the topic, could you help me with troubleshooting?

This is my docker-compose.yml

version: '3.2'
services:

```
  core:
    container_name: 'core'
    build: ./core/
    ports:
      - '8000:3000'
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
      NODE_PORT: '3000'
      CORE_HOST: 'core'
      CORE_PORT: '8000'
      CONTACTS_HOST: 'contacts'
      CONTACTS_PORT: '8100'
      MONGO_URI: 'mongodb://db:27017'
    restart: always

  contacts:
    container_name: 'contacts'
    build: ./contacts/
    ports:
      - '8100:3100'
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
      NODE_PORT: '3100'
      CORE_HOST: 'core'
      CORE_PORT: '8000'
      CONTACTS_HOST: 'contacts'
      CONTACTS_PORT: '8100'
      MONGO_URI: 'mongodb://db:27017'
    restart: always
```

and these are the two Dockerfiles

```
FROM node:9.6.0-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src && mkdir -p /usr/src/core
WORKDIR /usr/src/core
COPY . /usr/src/core
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm install && npm run start



FROM node:9.6.0-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src && mkdir -p /usr/src/contacts
WORKDIR /usr/src/contacts
COPY . /usr/src/contacts
EXPOSE 3100
CMD npm install && npm run start
```

Comment: I solved it.

I did not hand over the hostname because I gently say "it's all localhost" @_@